# Getting parse error when building an image with meta-swupdate using Yocto

Tags: yocto, swupdate

I'm trying to design an OTA update system and would like to use meta-swupdate with Yocto, here is what I did:

1. `bitbake-layers add-layer ../meta-openembedded/meta-oe/`
2. `bitbake-layers add-layer ../meta-swupdate`
3. `bitbake-layer showlayers`

```sh
NOTE: Starting bitbake server...
layer                 path                                      priority
==========================================================================
meta                  /home/ut/repo/poky/meta                   5
meta-poky             /home/ut/repo/poky/meta-poky              5
meta-yocto-bsp        /home/ut/repo/poky/meta-yocto-bsp         5
meta-oe               /home/ut/repo/os-dev/yocto/meta-openembedded/meta-oe  6
meta-swupdate         /home/ut/repo/os-dev/yocto/meta-swupdate  6
```

In `conf/local.conf`: I set `MACHINE ?= "qemuarm64"`

And build:

`bitbake swupdate-image`

This is what I get:

```sh
ERROR: ParseError at /home/ut/repo/os-dev/yocto/meta-swupdate/recipes-support/swupdate/swupdate.inc:10: unparsed line: 'LICENSE:${PN}-lua = "LGPLv2+"'                                     | ETA:  --:--:--

Summary: There was 1 ERROR message shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Could you please specify what version of poky are you using in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use the `master` branch of https://github.com/sbabic/meta-swupdate

Use the branch that is compatible with your `poky` branch. (dunfell, zeus, ...)

For example, in `dunfell` branch it is fixed:

```
LICENSE_${PN}-lua = "LGPLv2+"
LICENSE_${PN}-www = "MIT"
```